# Python: Having problem installing openpyxl with cmd and pycharm

Tags: openpyxl

When ever I try to install openypyxl using pip install openpyxl or python install setup.py I do receive error like:[could not find a version that satisfies the requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moOMH.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems python cant establish a connection. Are you connected to the Internet? Are you behind a proxy? If yes, deactivate it if you can.